# HTML5 - Document Outline - can we have a h1 after a p element on a header?

Tags: html, header

```
<article>
<header>
<p>Author bla bla</p><time datetime="2009-10-22" pubdate>October 22, 2009</time>
<h1>The big title on here</h1>
</header>
<p>some resume</p>
</article>
```

Will not this screw the **document outline** ? 
I'm asking this, because, visually, they should appear on that order.

Comment: In your code, `</header` does not have `>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the `<p>`, nor indeed the `<header>` element have any effect on the document outline. For outline purposes, in your example, the `<h1>` becomes the heading of its containing section, which is delimited by the `<article>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a `<h1>` can follow a `<p>`

Comment: Obviously, thanks for your answer. Still, a reason why, or a source will be a nice feature to add. :)

Comment: there is no formal DTD for HTML5 (that I am aware of), so it's best to use something similar (XHTML1), and follow its rules plus the additions that HTML5 provide.

In XHTML, h1 is of type "block", and blocks can follow blocks. as simple as that! http://www.w3.org/TR/html/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict

Comment: also, I see that your `<h1/>` is actually following a `<time/>`, which is inline, not block. still doesn't matter, though, as that's also allowed.

Comment: @Kae Verens: There is a [working draft of the HMTL5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element) that specifies that `header` may contain any flow content (almost every element) except `header` and `footer`. The term *block elements* is not used in this draft.

Comment: @Yogu and Kae Verens - My question was not that of asking IF we can have a p inside a h, we can have, and we can have even more as stated. My question is: "If we put P before H1 are we screwing the *document outline* ?

Answer (score -2):

Although a `<p>` can live after a `<h1>` it is still improper and bad for the DOM to create a header inside of a `<p>`.

```
<html>
<body>

    <!-- Unconventional: The <h1> has a larger scope than <p> and should not
                         live inside of it.  -->

    <p><h1>Hello? Yes this is answer.</h1></p>

    <!-- Conventional: The <h1> is larger in scope than <p> and the <p> is 
                       inside of the <h1>. -->

    <h1><p>Hello? Yes this is answer.</h1></p>   

</body>
</html>
```

In the same way, `<p>` and `<h1>` can appear in any order as long as they follow good scoping conventions.

Comment: No. `<p>` must not be placed inside a `<h1>`. But in the question, a `<h1>` just *follows* `<p>`, and that's valid.